# How to use SDWebImage in my project

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

Iam using collectionview to load image.These images are loaded from url in background thread. Hence the scrolling is not smooth.The images in url get expired after seconds hence i want to update the image with new image.How can i use the SDWebImage to load image and make scrolling smooth? Can anyone please help me to solve this.

Comment: can you please add some codes , so we can check what you are doing ?

Comment: I want to save the image using an inter value .How is it possible

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
[YOUR_CELL_NAME.YOUR_IMAGE_NAME setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"IMAGE URL"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PLACEHOLDER IMAGE NAME"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate the sdwebimage classes in your code. After that make a import.

Download [sdwebimage from here](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
```

and in your collectionview method write following lines to download image in backend thread.

```
[YOUR_CELL_NAME.YOUR_IMAGE_NAME setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"IMAGE URL"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PLACEHOLDER IMAGE NAME"]];
```

Comment: Yes I did that, but the image that are loaded are all expired images. i want to download image  and save it. i have no idea in code where this saving actually happens.

Comment: You need to clear the cache. SDImageCache *imageCache = [SDImageCache sharedImageCache];
[imageCache clearMemory];
[imageCache clearDisk];

Comment: Once i get an image downloaded it is shown in all imageviewsvof collection view cells.But iam passing different urls

Comment: I want to save the image using an inter value .Can someone please help,